# Coercing numbers to lists in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I'd like to turn integers into lists. For example, 2245 => (2 2 4 5).

I dislike `(coerce (write-to-string 2245) 'list)` because it yields `(#\2 #\2 #\4 #\5)`.

Help please?

Comment: Surely someone can post an implementation using `(loop ...)` ??

Comment: someone downvoted all the 'math' answers that use division and mod.  care to explain why you dont like them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(map 'list #'digit-char-p (prin1-to-string n))
```

works well.

Comment: No it doesn't: (map 'list #'digit-char-p (prin1-to-string -2455)) gives (NIL 2 4 5 5)

Comment: Amended:
 
`(map 'list (lambda (c)(or (digit-char-p c) '-)) (prin1-to-string n))`

Answer (score 7):

```
(defun number-to-list (n)    
  (loop for c across (write-to-string n) collect (digit-char-p c)))
```

An alternative loop based solution.

Answer (score 2):

Same as jon_darkstar but in common lisp. This fails for negative numbers, but trivial to amend.

```
(defun number-to-list (number)
  (assert (and (integerp number)
               (>= number 0)))
  (labels ((number-to-list/recursive (number) (print number)
             (cond
               ((zerop number)
                nil)
               (t
                (cons (mod number 10) 
                      (number-to-list/recursive (truncate (/ number 10))))))))
    (nreverse (number-to-list/recursive number))))
```

Comment: hadnt thought of negatives.  what would even be desired behavior?  every list element negative?  just the first?

Comment: I guess it depends on your interpretation of what the list represents. e.g. '(1 1) is 11 = 1*10^1 + 1. '(-1 1) would be -1*10^1 + 1 = -9.

Answer (score 2):

Common Lisp implementation for non-negative integers:

```
(defun number-to-list (n &optional tail)
  (if (zerop n)
    (or tail '(0))
    (multiple-value-bind (val rem)
                         (floor n 10)
      (number-to-list val (cons rem tail)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really use common lisp, but I'd do it like this in Scheme.  hopefully that can help?

```
(define (number-to-list x)
  (define (mod-cons x l)
     (if (zero? x)
         l
         (mod-cons (quotient x 10) (cons (remainder x 10) l))))
  (mod-cons x '()))

 (number-to-list 1234)
```

Comment: I think this has a syntax error. Also it doesn't seem to work when I port it to clisp lingo.

Comment: also just changed regular division to `quotient` (integer division).  just tested in the interpreter, it works

Comment: im not familiar with clisp, but i dont use anything besides function definition, integer division, mod, and cons.  id have to image clisp has all of those.  maybe use `(= x 0)` instead of `(zero? x)`  ??

Answer (score 0):

A variation on @Mark Cox's solution that also includes the '-' sign in case of negative integers. Inspired by @Terje Norderhaug's amendment to @rhombidodecahedron's solution, where negative numbers are represented by including a negative sign before the digits.

```
(defun number-to-numlist (number)
  "Converts an integer to a list of its digits. Negative numbers
are represented by a '-' sign prepended to the digits of its absolute value."
  (assert (integerp number))
  (labels ((collect-digits (number number-components list-of-numbers)
             (setf number-components (multiple-value-list (floor number 10)))
             (if (zerop number)
                 (or list-of-numbers '(0))
                 (collect-digits (first number-components) nil
                                 (cons (second number-components) list-of-numbers)))))
    (let ((number-list (collect-digits (abs number) nil nil)))
      (if (< number 0)
          (append '(-) number-list)
          number-list))))
```