# How to get a single digit from an integer in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Coercing numbers to lists in common lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559386/coercing-numbers-to-lists-in-common-lisp)

I am a beginner in common lisp.

If I have the number 123456890 and I want to get the numbers 1 2 3 5 9 separately how do I do it in common lisp?

Comment: How would you do it in _any_ language?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything in common lisp. I remember a long time ago I had tried using for loops and "% 10"s in C but it didn't work no matter how I changed it and also there was a problem when one of the digits was 0.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, obviously, this problem was solved before multiple times, and you had to search for the solution, before you asked, because otherwise you made it harder for others to find a good solution. So, here's one older answer: [Coercing numbers to lists in common lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559386/coercing-numbers-to-lists-in-common-lisp)

```
(defun int-to-list (int)
  (assert (>= int 0) nil "Argument must be non-negative")
  (if (= int 0) (list 0)
      (loop with result = nil
         while (> int 0) do
           (multiple-value-bind (divisor remainder)
               (floor int 10)
             (push remainder result)
             (setf int divisor))
         finally (return result))))
```